# If an error occurs ignore and give null value and continue with next cell

Tags: vba, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

The issue I'm facing is with error handling in VBA, My code runs fine but when the placeholder can't be allocated to address with the Google API it takes the previous cell's address. I need it to say NULL instead of taking the previous cell's data and giving me duplicate data.

```
Sub myTest()
On Error Resume Next
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Value = "Address: NULL "
End If
Dim xhrRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim domDoc As DOMDocument60
Dim domDoc2 As DOMDocument60
Dim placeID As String
Dim query As String
Dim nodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim node As IXMLDOMNode

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("C2:C3")

For Each cell In rng

'you have to replace spaces with +
query = cell.Value

'You must acquire a google api key and enter it here
Dim googleKey As String
googleKey = "Api Key" 'your api key here

'Send a "GET" request for place/textsearch
Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60

xhrRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?" & _
    "query=" & query & "&key=" & googleKey, False
xhrRequest.send

'Save the response into a document
Set domDoc = New DOMDocument60
domDoc.LoadXML xhrRequest.responseText

'Find the first node that is called "place_id" and is the child of the "result" node
placeID = domDoc.SelectSingleNode("//result/place_id").Text

'recycling objects (could just use new ones)
Set domDoc = Nothing
Set xhrRequest = Nothing

'Send a "GET" request for place/details
Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60
xhrRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" & placeID & _
"&key=" & googleKey, False
xhrRequest.send

'Save the response into a document
Set domDoc = New DOMDocument60
domDoc.LoadXML xhrRequest.responseText

Dim output As String
Dim s As String

'hacky way to get postal code, you might want to rewrite this after learning 
 more
 Set nodes = domDoc.SelectNodes("//result/*")
 For Each node In nodes
 s = node.Text
 If node.nodeName = "formatted_address" Then
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Address: " & s
End If
Next node

Next cell
'output
'MsgBox "Formatted Address: " & 
domDoc.SelectSingleNode("//result/formatted_address").Text & output
End Sub
```

This is what I get:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Comment: I tested your code and it left D2:D3 empty. After reading it I don't think that it would produce the first screenshot. Are you sure that the screenshot is produced by this code? (Try to delete the value of D2:D3, run the code, and see if it gets filled.)

Comment: The examples I gave is made up data, but yes the code is running fine when company names are put into C2:C3, the problem for me lies in that when google can't find the companies address it takes the previous cell's data.

Comment: When I receive the results from Google, the response contains a single note: "REQUEST_DENIED The provided API key is invalid." Are you sure that the googleKey = "No!" is correct?

Comment: The No! indicates if I'm going to share my api key with the rest of the world, LOL

Comment: And does Google offer a mock account for testing purposes? If not, I cannot test the code provided. Please, rewrite it so that it conforms with the requirements of "minimal, complete and verifiable example". https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve